# How to programmatically connect to Windows XMing X11

Tags: node.js, windows, x11

I would like to **programmatically** (through node.js) **connect to a X11 server running on the localhost installed on Windows** to redirect the display of X application running on a remote linux server. For my use case, I'm considering Xming on my localhost but that's not a strong requirement.

I'm usually working on Linux and there I know I can connect either to the socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` or to `localhost:6000` to trigger some display on my localhost (see for example the code on node.js ssh2 https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#forward-remote-x11-connections).

However, I absolutely do not know how to proceed on Windows;

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe XMing also uses TCP port 6000 by default ( or at least it did few years ago ). Have you tried connecting same way as you usually do under LInux?

Comment: Indeed, you are right, simply TCP connecting to 6000 worked like a charm. Thank you for your help.